# change BehaviorSubject when click on the input or focus on that

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have a directive for input . i need when click or focus on that , send a flag ti other component .

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appDatepicker]'
})
export class DatepickerDirective implements DoCheck{

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private transport: TransportData<boolean>) {

  }

  ngDoCheck(): void {
    let element = this.el.nativeElement;
    if (element.onfocus !== null || element.onclick !== null) {
      this.transport.setListValue(true);
    } else {
      this.transport.setListValue(false);
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my input .

```
<input appDatepicker>
```

when the page is loading , attribute `onfocus` and `onclick` is null and it currect , but my problem is here : **when i  click on input it not do any thing . how can  i listen the input in directive for set `BehaviorSubject` ?????**

Comment: You appear to be missing some code for your question. Could you post all relevant code.

Comment: @KurtHamilton this is all of code

Comment: What's `TransportData<T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle host element events in a directive you can use `@HostListener`.

```js
@HostListener('focus', ['$event'])
focus(event) {
  console.log('gained focus');
}

@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
click(event) {
  console.log('clicked!');
}

@HostListener('blur', ['$event'])
blur(event) {
  console.log('lost focus');
}
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bg7rpl

**Emitting events**

You can emit your own events from the directive too, should you wish.

directive.ts

```js
@Output() myfocus: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();

@HostListener('focus', ['$event'])
focus(event) {
  this.myfocus.emit();
}
```

component.html

```html
<input appDatepicker (myclick)="onClick()" />
```